# Can in polymorphic lambda calculus two terms have identical normal forms if we assume that set of their possible types does not intersect?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Let us assume, that we have context $\Gamma$ and two terms $M_1$ and $M_2$ in polymorphic lambda calculus. Let us also assume, that intersection of their possible types in context $\Gamma$ is empty(we assume that both of these terms can be typed).
Is it possible for their normal forms to be identical?

Answer (score 0):

Just a sketch. Whether it works probably depends on the formalism you use.
If $M$ normalizes to $N$ and $\tau$ is a possible type for $N$, is then $\tau$ also a possible type for $M$?

If yes, then the answer to your question is *no*.
For assume $M_1, M_2$ both normalize to $N$ and $\tau$ is a possible type of $N$, then $\tau$ is a possible type for both $M_1$ and $M_2$ which you assumed to be impossible.